# Нужно ли веб программирование для разработчика на С++?

Tags: c++, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, занимаюсь программирование около полугода, программирую на с++. Был заказ на сайт, решил разобраться и сделать. Я быстро разобрался в основах и выполнил задачу, так как там было не очень сложно. Сейчас появился ещё один, но намного сложнее. Начал изучать js одновременно с с++ и стараюсь разделять время на оба дела. (Ситуация позволяет учится и практиковаться практически весь день).

На данный момент я не могу точно ответить на то, чем я хочу в будущем заниматься, так как ещё нет каких-то предпочтений и полного понимания индустрии. На примете разработка мобильных приложений либо что-то из системного программирования, непосредвенно веб-разработчиком быть желания нет.

Вопрос таков, имеет ли смысл изучать веб и сможет ли это как-то мне пригодиться в будущем, если я выберу что-то из вышеперечисленного и насколько вообще необходимо (ну или хотя бы как-то помогает) знание веба для программистов на с++ или с#, например. Есть ли какая-то взаимосвязь, или же без цели становится веб программистом изучать это в какой-либо степени не имеет смысла?

Comment: Знание протоколов типа HTTP точно не помешает. Насчет остального - к цыганкам, они, говорят, неплохо будущее предсказывают.

Comment: Как говорил мой дед, "что знаешь и умеешь - за плечами не носить"...

Comment: Немного разбираться в вебе стоит хотя бы потому, что приходится все время лазить по сайтам. А C++ разработчику вообще-то может понадобится что угодно от знания кузнечного дела до выращивания кактусов.

Answer (score 1):

У вас за основу взят отличный язык C++, выбор вашей профессии не ограничен. По поводу веба, веб это некая часть сетевого программирования, сетевое программирования, тесно связано с системным программированием, соответсвенно можно пойти от обратного, можно из середины, можно разрабатывать ПО. Вас никто ни к чему не принуждает, что нравится, то и выбирайте, так вы будете получать и удовольствие, и доход, главное чтобы последнее не было вашей единственной целью...

Comment: То есть вот эти все "как мне сделоть текст пад углом на CSS" тесно связаны с написанием драйверов/загрузчиков и т.п.?

Comment: Ну «CSS», больше относится к верстке, а не к веб программированию.

Answer (score -2):

Если вы хотите например сделать игру через интернет, шашки карты... или удалённая св`яз с вашей программой то не плохо знать ещё PHP как минимум хотя для этих задач его хватит и как максимум. Библиотеки для упрощённой роботы с интернетом через С++ например POCO C++ Libraries или библиотека cURL. ещё много есть Но они не стандартные, если вы только начинаете программировать на С++ Вам обизательно нужно научиться устанавливать нестандартные библиотеки.

Но например если вы захотите отправлять команды своей программе с браузера, то не плохо изучить HTML А чтобы еще и красиво и разноцветно было то и CSS тоже.

Ваабще вэб немного бесит Чтобы с ним работать болие мение полноценно нужно сразу аж 3 языка учить.

Ответ Изучать нужно но не обязательно, по опыту скажу что рано или поздно все равно вам придется это сделать. Но во избежание путанице в голове лучше сначала с C++ начать себя комфортно чувствовать.